# How to make my method return a list instead of strings?

Tags: python

```
    def preorder(self):
        if self.root != None:
            self._preorder(self.root)

    def _preorder(self, cur_node):
        lyst = []
        if cur_node != None:
            lyst.append(str(cur_node.data))
        #print(str(cur_node.data))
            lyst += self._preorder(cur_node.left_child)
            lyst += self._preorder(cur_node.right_child)
        return lyst
```

So i have this preorder method that would just print out a bunch of strings of numbers on the terminal, for example like this:

```
277
291
295
385
317
309
301
306
313
314
362
351
328
321
325
323
343
335
334
342
346
344
345
347
361
355
357
378
377
390
399
```

However I am wanting it to be a list instead. So I made a empty list, and tried appending it, and also extending it to the recursive calls. However, this is still returning None. What exactly am i missing here?

Comment: you need to return something from `preorder`

Answer (score 1):

Your `_preorder` function returns a list, but your `preorder` function doesn't do anything with it.

```
def preorder(self):
    if self.root != None:
        self._preorder(self.root)  # nothing is done with this value
    # end of function -- no return so we return None
```

You could change this to:

```
def preorder(self):
    return self._preorder(self.root)
```

and now the caller of `preorder` will get a list as a return value.  Since `_preorder` handles the `None` case by returning an empty list it seems like `preorder` should just call it unconditionally.